# how to use let clause

Tags: elisp

I am a beginner to elisp. I am facing an error evaluating the simple code given below:

```
(let (set-id 1) (
(message set-id))
```

I am getting the error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function (message set-id))
  ((message set-id))
  eval(((message set-id)) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp()
  call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
```

Can anyone show me some light?

Comment: Try `(let ((set-id 1) (message set-id)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper syntax is this:

```
(let ((set-id 1)) 
  (message "%s" set-id))
```

Comment: And the explanation is that the first argument is a list of bindings.  Each binding is either the name of a variable, or a list of variable name, value.  So you can say `(let (foo bar) (elisp code ...))` which is effectively the same as `(let ((foo nil) (bar nil)) (elisp code ...))`